# Tableview and UIbutton simultaneously touchdownpress registered input order on which button is let loose first

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following problem occurs in my project, when i pressed and hold a backbutton (uibarbuttonitem) and a tableview row. And letting go the tableview row and followed by letting go the backbutton the following error occurs:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'.

I have figured out the problem here is that the tableview didselectrowatindexpath has wrong indexpath.

**Case:** A uibarbuttonitem and a tableview row is pressed and hold simultaneously.

**In situation 1:** The uibarbuttonitem is letting go and followed by letting go the tableview row.
Result: Selector for uibarbuttonitem is called. (In my case no error.)

**In situation 2:** The tableview row is letting go and followed by letting go the uibarbuttonitem.
Result: Selector for uibarbuttonitem is called and followed by the delegate methods of tableview. (In my case the error above occurs.)

```
- (void)backbutton {
   self.itemList = [self getOldItem];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // It crash on this line.
    Model *model = [[self.itemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [model show];
}
```

Does anyone know if this is a normal behavior for which order the selector methods of those button are called? And how i should handle this?

Comment: check for indexPath.section. i think this will return nil

Comment: are you sure your array has the items in it?

Comment: In situation 2, the error occurs because the indexPath doesnt match with the the datasource. The datasource of the tableview is changed in the method backbutton, after that the didSelectRowAtIndexPath will be called but it has the indexPath from the datasource before the backbutton method is called. I do not know how to prevent didSelectRowAtIndePath from executing that line of code (the code above with the comment) if the indexPath doesn't match with the the datasource.